# asp.net mvc and recaptcha action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, captcha, interceptor, action-filter

When a user submits a form, i'd like to show/redirect to the captcha page intermittently ( based on some custom rules ) and if validated, then execute/commit the first action

Is there a way of doing this using the ActionFilter ?
or any other way ?

Comment: I've post code on how to do this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611122/how-to-implement-recaptcha-for-asp-net-mvc/7805612#7805612

Comment: NuGet **Google reCAPTCHA V2** for MVC 4 and 5

- [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/reCAPTCH.MVC/)
- [Demo And Document](http://recaptchamvc.apphb.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This is also:
http://eglasius.blogspot.com/2010/10/adding-recaptcha-to-aspnet-mvc.html