# WebControlCaptcha image MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, captcha

I converted my MVC3 application from aspx to Razor, I am using Captcha; in the aspx I used:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" Namespace="WebControlCaptcha" Assembly="WebControlCaptcha" %>
```

In the Razor project I moved register to web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="WebControlCaptcha" namespace="WebControlCaptcha" tagPrefix="cc1" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

Unfortunately the Captcha image did not display, any suggestions.  Thank you.

Comment: How are you embedding the captcha helper on the page?

Comment: I did using:    <cc1:CaptchaControl ID="CaptchaControl1" runat="server"></cc1:CaptchaControl>.  This is wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are user controls from WebForms, which are not supported in MVC. Instead of user controls you will need HTML helpers.

Not sure if the control you are trying to use has an MVC equivalent, if not, I would recommend this question that covers how to do (re)CAPTCHA in MVC:

[How to implement reCaptcha for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611122/how-to-implement-recaptcha-for-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thanks, I did look at reCaptcha; it will requires making considerable changes to my existing code.

Comment: I found this CaptchaMVC, http://vvson.net/Projects/en-US/Documentation/captchamvc-getting-started#content.  Very simple to implement and also don't have to sign for a google account.

Answer (score 0):

See your version of IIS if 6 or 7.

Change 
 - IIS 6 in 
 - IIS 7 in

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Free-ASP.Net-Mathematical-Captcha-Control-in-VB.Net-and-C.aspx