# ASP.net MVC C# Recaptcha on Identity Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, recaptcha

I am trying to implement Googles reCaptcha on my `MVC` *ASP.net* project following the instructions found on the third to the top answer of this post, [How to implement reCaptcha for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611122/how-to-implement-recaptcha-for-asp-net-mvc/7805612#7805612). Currently I have downloaded and included the proper dependencies

```
using reCAPTCHA.MVC;
```

My login method looks like :

```
 // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [CaptchaValidator(
    PrivateKey = "your private reCaptcha Google Key",
    ErrorMessage = "Invalid input captcha.",
    RequiredMessage = "The captcha field is required.")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

And in my view I am adding the captcha inside my :

```
@html.beginform(){

        @Html.Recaptcha()
        @Html.ValidationMessage("ReCaptcha")
}
```

I also have my public and private keys added into my `web.config` file. 
However when I run everything on the login page, the `captcha` box shows up, except there is no where to click and I get the `error` :

> "ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key" where the box to click in the captcha box should be.

In addition I have tried to reset the keys but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the response in Controller

> var response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];

you can easily implement reCaptcha i have found an example in search, i hope this helps

> https://www.codeproject.com/articles/874150/google-recaptcha-in-asp-net-mvc