# How to enable button if recaptcha is valid

Tags: asp.net, button, asp.net-mvc-5, recaptcha, captcha

I have controler named `AccountController` with recaptcha and code like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FormSubmit()
        {

            var response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
            string secretKey = "6Lf_NnQUAAA......";  //Added my secret key that genereted on my re-captcha
            var client = new WebClient();
            var result = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response{1}", secretKey, response));
            var obj = JObject.Parse(result);
            var status = (bool)obj.SelectToken("success");
            ViewBag.Message = status ? "successs" : "failed";

            return View();
        }
```

Also, I have  `LogIn.cshtml` view with code like this:

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("FormSubmit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lf_NnQUAAA..."></div> //ADDED MY SITE KEY
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Join IoT Lab!">  
    }
</div>
<span style="display:inline-block; font-size:20px;margin:20px 0;padding:20px;border:1px solid #D3D3D3">
    @ViewBag.Message
</span>
<p>
    By clicking "Join IoT Lab", you agree to our <br />
    <a href="@Url.Action("PrivacyRulesAndGuidelines", "IOTLabProject")">Terms and conditions</a> and <a href="@Url.Action("PrivacyRulesAndGuidelines", "IOTLabProject")">Privacy policy</a>
</p>

<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Currently, captcha using images for validating, so if I check right images captcha will be valid, but also if I just click submit ("Join IoT Lab") without captcha it will still redirect me...

**So, how to enable `Join IoT Lab!` (commit) button after validating the recaptcha? I mean, how to set recaptcha as required field?**

I suppose I should use something like `ViewBag`, but how?

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's not. I'm not using javascript or jQuery.

Comment: There are a lot of answers on [How to implement reCaptcha for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4611122)

Answer (score 0):

You can check viewBag.Message condition on your "Join IoT Lab!" button.This message 
is enable after form submit.Maybe i understand your problem and giving a right solution.if you have any problem ,please know me.

```
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("FormSubmit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lf_NnQUAAA..."></div> //ADDED MY SITE KEY
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Join IoT Lab!">  
}
</div>
<span style="display:inline-block; font-size:20px;margin:20px 
0;padding:20px;border:1px solid #D3D3D3">
@ViewBag.Message
</span>
<p>
@if(ViewBag.Message=="successs")
{
  By clicking "Join IoT Lab", you agree to our <br />
  <a href="@Url.Action("PrivacyRulesAndGuidelines", "IOTLabProject")">Terms and 
   conditions</a> and <a href="@Url.Action("PrivacyRulesAndGuidelines", 
   "IOTLabProject")">Privacy policy</a>
}

 </p>

<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
```