# I want to call method from view written in controller using image tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I want to call a method from view written in the controller using image tags in the Asp.net mvc project. What should I do?

Below is my HTML code written in View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginSuccess", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
 {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      <form>
   <p><img src="/Login/ShowCaptchaImage" /></p>
                                                <p>Please enter the string as shown above:</p>
                                                <p>@Html.TextBox("CaptchaText")</p>
                                                <strong>@ViewBag.Message</strong>
   </form>
}
```

I want to call ShowCaptchaImage() method on login page load.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in similar Stackoverflow question. There are demos and how to implement is also available there.

[How to implement reCaptcha for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611122/how-to-implement-recaptcha-for-asp-net-mvc)

Is your requirements different from this? Or Missed that resources?

Comment: <p><img src="/Login/ShowCaptchaImage" /></p>  -------This img tag not working for me for calling ShowCaptchaImage() action method written in Login controller