# MVC form Calculation field

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am thinking about adding a field  in my form that will ask the user to answer a question like what is 5 + 3. Any human can answer it but a bot won't know what to do since it is auto-populating fields based on field names. So that field will be either incorrect or missing in which case the submission will be rejected. In my view I am thinking to return two number have the users answer the three number and on form Submission check the Calculation. Any help would be great.

Comment: Help with what? I guess this is a primitive type of captcha, but you seem to have figured out exactly what you want to do. Where exactly are you stuck? What have you tried, what went wrong? On this site you need to ask a fairly specific question, you can't just write "any help" and expect us to figure out what you need

Comment: Is that useful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611122/how-to-implement-recaptcha-for-asp-net-mvc