# mvc 3 recaptcha not using Razor but just aspx engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, recaptcha

currently using mvc 3 and every time i search how to use ReCaptcha on it id always find something that uses microsoft.web.helpers and razor. I know i can use the razor engine with the regular aspx but id rather not just to avoid confusion. Anywho, I'm having problems on how to call the recaptcha on the aspx using microsoft.web.helpers. I guess my question is, am i even using the right references for the aspx engine?

any help is appreciated.

Thanks!
g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it in MVC 2, however this should work fine in MVC 3 since you are using the ASPX rendering engine.

http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/12/02/using-recaptcha-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Here is another solution:

http://mvcrecaptcha.codeplex.com/

Duplicate of:
[asp.net mvc and recaptcha action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178305/asp-net-mvc-and-recaptcha-action)

Comment: yeah i think those were the other links that i saw before. and it's using recaptcha dll. was wondering if the mvc.web.helpers will suffice? no?

Comment: http://ihatethissite.com/blog/2011/02/27/recaptcha-with-asp-net-mvc-razor-using-microsoft-web-helpers/

Just change the @{ to <%.

Comment: awesome! but one question tho, how do i make it appear only after a certain number of failed attempts?

Answer (score 0):

The code in below links work perfectly in my MVC 3 project

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=611